# Scala Functional "no-op" syntax

Tags: scala

I have some code that does this = :

```
{
    val data = someBlackBox.loadData()
    LOG.(s"Got ${data.size} record(s)")
    data
}
```

Three lines seems a bit inelegant when all I want to do is log the size of the data (a `Set`) and return the data. Is there `someMethod` on `Set` where:

```
someBlackBox.loadData().someMethod(data => LOG(s"Got ${data.size} record(s)"))
```

...so `someMethod` works a bit like `map` but isn't intended to transform `data` into another type - merely perform some operation on it, and return it?

Or maybe an altogether better way of doing this?